# What hyper referencing package is compatible with MiKTeX 1.20e?

Tags: hyperref, packages, miktex

I am looking for the basic functionality of the `hyperref` in a package that would be compatible with MiKTeX 1.20e. (This is needed for uploading files to an organization which supports MiKTeX 1.20e but not later.) I want to be able to refer to sections and tables in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several packages paired with MikTeX 1.20e.

Warning: For any of these to have a reasonable possibility of working you need to have a consistent installation of MikTeX 1.20e on your authoring machine and you will have to find these versions of the packages.

It is possible that later versions will be compatible but no guarantee.

hyphmsec ver 2.1 2000  puts links in section headings

hyper 1999 puts links in tex files

hyperlatex 2.3.1 1998 put links in pdf files

hypernat  1.0a 2001 allows putting links in bibtex bibliographies

hyperref  6.73n 2003 release  (this has been updated many times since then and the latest I know is not compatable with 1.20e.

A final challenge.  MikTeX 1.20e (to the best of my memory) will not run on XP, Vista, or Windows 7.  (possibly this can be gotten around using a virtual machine)